# How do I make gemspec dependencies autoload in a Rails 3 app, using a Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, dependencies, bundler, rails-engines

I have a Rails 3 app that I am turning into a Rails engine / gem.
This engine has some gem dependencies that I have put inside it's .gemspec file.

I have created a new 'parent' Rails 3 app, and I would like to add my engine gem to the Gemfile and have the gem's dependencies automatically 'loaded', but this does not work for me! `bundle install` installs the gem dependencies fine, but when I start the server, the app crashes because they are not loaded.

For example, my engine's gemspec contains these lines:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<rails>, ["= 3.0.7"])
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<acts_as_commentable>, [">= 3.0.1"])
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<haml>, [">= 3.1.1"])
```

.. and the parent Rails 3 application has these lines in its Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'my_engine', :path => "~/src/gems/my_engine"
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_commentable'
from /home/user/src/gems/my_engine/app/models/account.rb:66:in `<class:Account>'
```

But if I add `gem 'acts_as_commentable', '>= 3.0.1'` to the Gemfile of the parent Rails 3 app, then the gem is loaded and the error disappears.

I am using Rails 3.0.8.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Do I need to change something about the way my engine is loading?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

During main Rails app boot, Bundler will only require dependencies directly listed in the Gemfile but not any sub-dependencies. **It's your library's/Engine's responsibility to require its dependencies when it itself gets required.** You can do so using initializers in your Railtie.

```
class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  initializer "require stuff" do
    require "stuff"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming that this is the expected behaviour. There's a closed (rejected) issue on bundler with the idea of 'recursive Gemfiles', which sounds like it might have been useful: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/49

Comment: For me I needed to require in /lib/my_engine.rb. Example: https://github.com/krisleech/qwerty/commit/c1e82cef27013afc6a540412e101cc2b6aeb4898

Answer (score 3):

In our Rails Engine we used a small trick to require dependencies automatically. Unfortunately you can't specify whether or not they should load in the .gemspec, which would allow for greater control.

```
Gem.loaded_specs["our_rails_engine"].dependencies.each do |d|
  begin
    require d.name
  rescue LoadError => le
    # Put exceptions here.
    raise le if d.name !~ /factory_girl_rails/
  end
end
```

Comment: That works really well, though I'm doing `runtime_dependencies` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at Spree (the superhero of Rails Engines!), and they do this in `spree_core-0.60.1/lib/spree_core.rb`:

```
require "rails/all"

require 'state_machine'
require 'paperclip'
require 'stringex'
require 'will_paginate'
require 'nested_set'
require 'acts_as_list'
require 'resource_controller'
require 'active_merchant'
require "meta_search"
require "find_by_param"
```

So the answer is that within your gem, you have to require all of it's gem dependencies one by one. Well, that's how I will do it for now. But please comment if this ever changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it don't work, i create a host project and a sub-project with rails 3 engine.

Added the gem to engine's gemspec

`s.add_dependency 'simple_form'`

then added the require to engine_name.rb like below

`require 'simple_form'`

But if delete the line [gem 'simple_form'] in host project's Gemfile, it will show undefined immediatly